# Automatically picking high-poly / low-poly model based on distance to camera?

Tags: rendering, mesh

I'm trying to model a city, and I was wondering if Blender somehow supports "level of detail", i.e. something like this:

1. I create multiple versions of the same buildings that differ by
   polygon count (low-poly model, medium-poly, high-poly...).
2. When I hit render, Blender will automatically choose between these
   versions based on distance to the camera, so that far away buildings
   use low-poly models, and nearby buildings high-poly models.

Does Blender support this directly? If not, can it be done via scripting?

For further clarification, I'm not trying to build a game, I just want to render some scenes in different parts of the city. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible outside of the game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Level Of Detail](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Kupoman/Level_Of_Detail)  settings in Blender 2.7 will be only available in the game engine.

Someone else had an approach to control the subdivisions of a multires modifier using a driver and use the distance from cam to an object.

[image]

See this [Blog post](http://reynantem.blogspot.de/2011/11/blender-mesh-lod-test.html) detailed information and demo file.

It does not support switching different meshes only subdivision nor LoD for different textures.

---

My approach would be to have different Objects / Meshes parented and calculate the distance from camera to each object. For a quick test I parented a lores version to a higher mesh version of a model.

Like so:
[image]

Depending on a distance threshold the visibility of the lores or the hires parent is easily controlled by a script:

```
import bpy

threshold = 9

scene = bpy.context.scene
camera = scene.objects["Camera"]
cam_pos = camera.location
print(cam_pos)
for ob in scene.objects:
    print( ob.name )
    if ob.name.startswith("Cube.LowRes"):
        d = cam_pos - ob.parent.location
        dist = d.length

        if dist > threshold:
            ob.hide = False
            ob.parent.hide = True
            ob.hide_render = False
            ob.parent.hide_render = True

        else:
            ob.hide = True
            ob.parent.hide = False
            ob.hide_render = True
            ob.parent.hide_render = False
        print( ob.location )       
        print( dist )
```

If you plan to use this with for an animated camera you could consider adding a [bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=frame_change_pre#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre) and call the script before each frame.

Demo file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27069)

Comment: That might work nicely with the Decimate modifier too..