# Rendering a large number of unique objects

Tags: workflow, memory-management

I've got a script which imports a bunch of hi-resolution models onto a grid. It gives me this:

[image]

It's currently got 35 objects (81924 vertices per object), but I'd like to rotate the camera toward the horizon, and arrange many many more objects out to infinity (~1500 of them).

I feel that a simple extension of what I'm doing now is going to run my machine out of memory. And since I only really need hi-res data close to the camera, it's a waste of resources out at the horizon.

What would be a good strategy for rendering many hi-res models in a single scene?

Comment: Are you instancing them? (dupli objects?)

Comment: do you really need 81924 vertices per object? You could add a decimate modifier to each of them and apply it. That can bring the poly count down a lot.

Comment: @gandalf3 the brains look unique

Comment: @gandalf3 yeah, the brains are all different

Comment: @vader I suppose I'd just have to experiment to find a good decimate ratio based on distance from the camera?

Comment: @ajwood You could [try a driver](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7308/599).

Comment: @ajwood You could check out the level of detail script because when your far distant hires models are rendered using only a few pixel in the image you actually don't need a detailed model see 2nd part of my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/automatically-picking-high-poly-low-poly-model-based-on-distance-to-camera

Comment: I would just decimate all of them to a rather low level. Or you could just pick a few ~20 brains and instance them, could you get away with this?

Comment: I'd keep some hi-res models close to the camera, then have a decimated copy that uses two array modifiers to fill the background. You could even bake a normal map to use on a very low poly shape for the background.

Comment: as it stands right now OP would end up at about 30 million polygons, probably more though.

Comment: Does instancing reduce render time? I've never heard about that until now, but if so, it's good to know. Is this also true for BI or just Cycles?

Comment: both support instancing. THe main improvement form instancing is the reduced ram load, with instances you can have virtually unlimited duplicates. Any speed increases gained might be side effects.

Comment: Would it be possible to split the brains into multiple scenes or layers and combine them using the compositor?

Comment: one brain is enough for me.

Comment: Instancing does not really help if each brain is an unique mesh.

Comment: Have you also made sure to remove doubles (duplicate/ very closely spaced vertices) from those models? It could cut down on vertices which would allow you to instance more parent models for the render.

Answer (score 4):

You could group all the brains (Ctrl-G) and then use the brain group in a particle system on a grid which emits from each vertex. Make sure the number of vertices = number of particles. Also be sure to display your models as bounds only, otherwise Blender will try to draw all the detail in viewport. Using a particle system allows me to draw forests of complex trees, so I think brains should work too.

In the picture you see the group of objects in the front and the result of a particle system on a subdivided grid emitting from each vertex in the background.[image]

Comment: I think the problem is loading 1500 unique brains into memory, this method works fine with a small number of unique items

Comment: But I don't see why you would need 1500 unique brains. As long as those in the foreground are unique and those beyond that a random selection of the foreground brains, the observer really won't notice the repetition. Heck even on these unique brains it's pretty hard to see.

Comment: Looking closer I think I already see duplicates, second row, 3rd, 4th column.
3rd row, 4th and 5th column.

Comment: I think in OPs image there are duplicates because OP cannot render even a few unique brains. I agree there only need to be a few unique in the render

Comment: 15 unique brains of 81924 vertices is about 1.2 million vertices. I think that shouldn't be a problem for even a moderate computer. Lets hope OP weighs in on the matter.

Comment: I think the problem is that OP want to do a fly through It might be somewhat obvious that there are a bunch of clones.

Comment: Sorry I've been MIA. My first step is going to be getting a render with lots of detail close to the camera, and random clones far away. But Vader is right that I'd like to be able to fly through to show off all of the uniqueness.

Comment: @David, you're right that there are duplicates here.. kind of an accident.

Comment: My motivation for making this image is to show off a huge number of unique brains, so I want to avoid obvious clones.

Comment: David, this is a good solution for the case where it's OK to make copies (which may be most cases), but I use Blender for scientific visualizations, and the animations must perfectly represent my data, or else the result would be similar to fabricating data.  I have also ran into memory problems importing my models into Blender, so I'm looking forward to seeing some more answers.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of it cutting the scene up into bits with the maximum amount of models you can run. Then rendering the same flightpath over each scene and compositing them.